# Validar un input radio con un loop for dentro de otro loop if

Tags: javascript, formularios, validación

...y hacer que funcione:
dejando el radio en null, debería saltar la alerta. Pero no lo hace y valida.

```
else if(false){     

        function check(){

            var r= document.getElementsByName("e");
            var e= -1;

            for(var i=0; i < r.length; i++){
                if(r[i].checked>=0){
                    e = i; 
                }
            }

            if (e>=0){                  
                return true;
            }

        }
            alert("Error: selecciona alguna opción");       
    }
```

No se que tengo que poner exactamente en la condición del else if para que funcione.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: A que te refieres con que funcione? Que es lo que tratas de hacer y que código está antes del else if?

Comment: No funciona. Dejando el radio en null, debería saltar la alerta. Pero no lo hace y valida.

Comment: No he puesto el resto del código porque es muy extenso. Pero es la típica validación de formulario con un loop if dentro de una función.

Comment: Hola @Nian_cat, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Para poder ayudarte sería de gran ayuda que describieras completamente el problema que tienes, el comportamiento esperado y el código completo relacionado a tu inquietud.

Comment: yo no se que es lo que esta preguntando exactamente pero esta linea -> else if(false){  en su codigo no la veo muy clara, porque usa if(false) creo que tendria que mirar eso. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo y lógica están bien, pero resulta que la propiedad checked no es de tipo numérico, sino que es más bien de tipo *booleano*.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#validar').click(function() {
    if (!check()) {
      alert('Debe seleccionar por lo menos una opción');
    } else {
      alert('Validación cumplida');
    }
  });
});

function check() {

  var r = document.getElementsByName("e");
  var e = -1;

  for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    if (r[i].checked == true) {
      e = i;
    }
  }

  if (e >= 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="e" />
  <a href="#!" id="validar">Validar</a>
</form>
```